# Fetching the attribute on class is not working using JQuery

Tags: jquery

When i click on the Edit button , the data attribute value as undefined, please let me know how to resolve this?

```
 <div role="main" class="ui-content oms-content">
            <div class="myactivelabelsWrap">
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                    <h3>Heading 1<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon" data_attr="123" >Edit</a></h3>
                    <ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL">
                        <li class="labellist">
                            <div class="leftlable">
                                <p>Content here</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
                    <h3>Heading 2<a class="icon-pencil-1 labelEditIcon" data_attr="345" >Edit</a></h3>
                   <ul data-role="listview" class="labellistUL ">
                        <li class="labellist">
                            <div class="leftlable">
                                <p>Content here</p>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

document.addEventListener(
    'click',
    function(event){
        if( $(event.target).is('.labelEditIcon')){
            var address_label = $(this).attr('data_attr');
            alert(address_label);
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    },
    true // Capture event
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/15/

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add the fiddle , just added that .http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/15/

Comment: `this === document`, you might still wanna use `event.target` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, `$(this)` refers to jquery object of document and not of target element.you need to target the element using event.target:

```
  var address_label = $(event.target).attr('data_attr');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gsejn2am/)**

**Suggestion:**

Attaching the click event to whole document is bad practice. You should rather attach the click event to only required element:

```
$('.labelEditIcon').click(function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('data_attr'));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

### Working Demo

Comment: I  have gone for the listener option , because , please see this fidlde http://jsfiddle.net/tdzfhzjy/18/

Comment: check the first demo from fiddle. that is what you are looking for.

Comment: yes , excllent its working fine , thank you very much .